# import org.jsoup.* not working

Tags: java, import, jsoup

I try to make a java app using Jsoup.

Instead of using

(A)

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.helper.Validate;
import org.jsoup.helper.Validate;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
```

I want to use

(B)

```
import org.jsoup.*;
```

(A) is working but (B) is not...

I am using IntelliJ and imported the dependencies...
Why is this not working ?

Comment: You need to add the Jsoup JAR file to project's build path. Drop the JAR in the project's root folder or some /lib folder, rightclick the JAR file and then choose Build Path > Add to Build Path. after that try the online import and tell us whether it works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should import each package like this:

```
import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.helper.*;
import org.jsoup.nodes.*;
import org.jsoup.select.*;
```

Since `org.jsoup` and `org.jsoup.helper` are different packages, you should import them separately.

In Eclipse, there is a function called `Organize Import`, perhaps there is similar functionality in InteliJ.

Comment: eclipse has ctrl+shift+O, very useful

Comment: implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.13.1' in Android Studio